Тег роли disnake.py
Подскажите кто знает как тегнуть роль через disnake.py

то есть чтобы приходило уведомление и сообщение подсвечивалось жёлтым


Изначально у тех у кого есть эта роль они будут получать уведомления когда боты выполняет команду. Для проверки выдайте себе роль Assistent chief и оно будет у вас тоже отображаться жёлтым.
